# Mostrar en la vista del usuario un valor INT como si fuera un String

Tags: laravel, angular

Mi modelo de Laravel tiene la columna creado_por definida como un valor INT. En la vista del usuario se esta imprimiendo como el ID del usuario que lo creo, pero yo quiero que se muestre como el atributo nombre_completo de la tala usuarios.

Mi controlador esta asi:

```
public function store(StoreRequest $request)
{
    $correo_duplicado = $this->correoDuplicado($request->correo);
    $user = Auth::user();
    $request->request->set('creado_por', $user->id);

    if ($correo_duplicado > 0) {
       \Alert::error(trans('La dirección de correo ya existe. Por favor, ingrese un nuevo correo.'))->flash();
        return redirect('admin/configuracion/compras_notificaciones');
    }

    // your additional operations before save here
    $redirect_location = parent::storeCrud($request);
    // your additional operations after save here
    // use $this->data['entry'] or $this->crud->entry
    return $redirect_location;

}
```

Y mi modelo y relaciones estan asi:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| FUNCTIONS
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
public function obtenerCreadoPor()
{
    //dd($this->creado_por);
    if($this->creado_por)
    {
        return  '<b>' .$this->creado_por.'<b/>';
    }
}
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RELATIONS
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'nombre_completo', 'id')->withTrashed();
}
```

¿Como logro enseñarle al usuario el nombre de la persona que lo creo, en lugar del ID?

Gracias.

Comment: Agrega el otro modelo e indicanos así mismo en el otro modelo que tipo de relación comparte

Comment: No comparten ninguna relación, solo esta llave foranea que cree con el id.

Comment: Pues esa es precisamente el punto de unión y si deben tener relación entre ellos puesto que tienes en uso el método `belongsTo()` entonces en el modelo contrario debería existir un hasOne o hasMany, entonces ¿qué relación comparten tus entidades?, una vez claro eso podemos construir la consulta